# I need help trying to authenticate with AD from my linux machine

Tags: windows, active-directory, postfix, ldap, dovecot

I am not experienced in this, so there might be some points that I am missing. Initially I tried to setup Cyrus Mail w/ SASL for AD authentication. After several tries, it failed to work.

I switched to Dovecot and authentication failed in Dovecot, too. So, I started troubleshooting:

1. I created a user in AD and called it "vmail".
2. ran `ldapsearch -x -h ad.example.com -D 'vmail' -W -b 'dc=example,dc=com' "(userPrincipalName=testuser@example.com)" and entered the password. The results were successful (returned the ldap user attributes)
3. Then I ran `ldapwhoami -x -W -D cn=vmail,dc=example,dc=com -h ad.example.com` and entered the password. However, this script fails with

   ```
   ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49)
      additional info: 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903A9, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v1db1
   ```

Dovecot and Postfix both fail on parameters similar to this. In Dovecot and Postfix I setup password attribute as `userPassword=password`. AD authentication works (e.g I can log in to my Windows machine that is connected to domain, using testuser@example.com).

The "vmail" user is a domain administrator and administrator (I wanted to be sure that being administrator has nothing to do with binding). I really started to think that the problem is in Windows Server not allowing authentication with Linux machines (is that a possibility?) because everything in Linux is correct (at least it looks like it is)

I am using CentOS 7.1.1503 (Core) if it matters.

EDIT: After more troubleshooting I have found that if I don't specify the domain controllers, ldapwhoami succeeds and returns the user:

```
ldamwhoami -x -W -D vmail -h ad.example.com
```

However, dovecot still doesn't work. I set `base =` (empty) to check it out and it still failed to authenticate.

Comment: where is your vmail user? Does it INDEED reside under "dc=example,dc=com" - it's quite unlikely for a user be placed right at the top. You want to find out vamail's DN first, and use correct DN in -D parameter.